# VBA HTML elements to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am working on a code that uses VBA-Excel to navigate to a website and copy some values to Excel.

I can open the website and navigate, but I can't save the "Precipitation" values in excel sheet

```
Sub accuweather()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim pagePiece As Object
Dim webpage As HTMLDocument

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True 

ie.navigate ("http://www.accuweather.com/en/pt/abadia/869773/daily-weather-forecast/869773?day=2")

Do While ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until ie.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Set webpage = ie.document
Set mtbl = webpage.getElementsByTagName("details-card card panel details allow-wrap")
Set table_data = mtbl.getElementsByTagName("div")(1)

For itemNum = 1 To 240
    For childNum = 0 To 5
        Cells(itemNum, childNum + 1) = table_data.Item(itemNum).Children(childNum).innerText
    Next childNum
Next itemNum

ie.Quit
Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: This is not a tag name _details-card card panel details allow-wrap_ Looks like multi-value class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are using is `getElementsByTagName` but the reference is for a multi-valued class. So the correct method would be `getElementsByClassName`.

However, you don't need the browser as that content is static and you can just use faster xmlhttp request and a single (more robust and faster) class to target.

This

```
html.querySelectorAll(".list")
```

is retrieving the two parent nodes which have the various p tag children. The first child in both cases

```
.Item(i).FirstChild
```

is the precipitation info.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetPrecipitationValues()
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument, i As Long

    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.accuweather.com/en/pt/abadia/869773/daily-weather-forecast/869773?day=2", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With html.querySelectorAll(".list")
        For i = 0 To .Length - 1
            Debug.Print .Item(i).FirstChild.innerText
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I am printing results to immediate window Ctrl + G but easy to write to sheet

Comment: Thanks QHarr. how can i print this results to excel?

Comment: Qharr sorry but i need to add a loop for each line URL (multiple URLS)

Comment: There are lots of example on stackoverflow showing you how to do this. I will share a link to some below so you can have a go at it first.  Have a look through these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Dim+urls+user%3A6241235+is%3Aanswer

Comment: i posted these question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59011071/excel-vba-loop . if you can help i will appreciate. tks again!